# why images in division are not appearing to banner block?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to edit my WordPress theme. On the home page, there is an option to have a slider and banner with two divisions. The slider is working fine, but the banner block is not appearing.

Code is like:

```
<div id="banner-block"> 
    <div class="head-banner">   
        <?php echo of_get_option('w2f_off_banner'); ?>  
    </div>
```

But the images are not getting called.

My site: http://www.dailydiscountdeals.in/

Comment: Please avoid posting external links. Instead, try to replicate your issue with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are just linking to the URL of the image. You should put the url in the image tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo of_get_option('w2f_off_banner'); ?>" width="xx" height="xx">
```